# For the solarian's Solar Manifestation is it consider magic for the purposes of "detect magic"?

Tags: starfinder

Exactly as stated is the Solar Manifestation magic and can it be detected by detect magic?

Answer (score 7):

**Yes**

Detect Magic detects "all magic spells, effects, items, and objects (including those on or affecting creatures you can see)" (Starfinder Core Rulebook pg. 348). Solar Manifestation is a supernatural ability as denoted by the "(SU)" tag (SCR 101). Supernatural abilities are explicitly magical (SCR 59).